# Error: Access denied for user "@localhost" using password yes on c panel

Tags: php, sql, database, cpanel

Im trying to access an sql database on c panel through a web hosting server. I have a user that has been created for the database and it has been granted all privileges. When I try to access the database through my domain+file path I get an error: Access denied for user "@localhost" using password yes on c panel.

I have tried command 
`SHOW GRANTS;`on the database, and it get the following:
`GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'cpses_hagmkcyksn'@'localhos...
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON`****_testdata`.* TO ...`

Any suggestions?